# How can i supply zeppelin jdbc interpreter password through env variable

Tags: apache-zeppelin

How can i supply zeppelin jdbc interpreter password through an env variable?
I dont want to use the ui to configure password. I will be using zeppelin server in a docker container which will have a dynamic user name and password preset in an env variable. Can zeppelin jdbc interpreter be made to read the user/password from these env variables?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add it to the configuration on your interpreter and get it from the SparkConfig:

```
sourceUser = sc._conf.get('db.sourceUser')
sourcePW = sc._conf.get('db.sourcePW')
```

Comment: As I was using kubernetes, I used a `PersistentVolume` to store the fullblown `conf/interpreter.json` (with hardcoded password) and in container start scripts copied the file from there to `$ZEPPELIN_HOME/conf`.
That way when zeppelin starts it will have the jdbc interpreter initialized correctly. I don't get your answer since the ask was how to place it in interpreter config before zeppelin starts.